# Can GeoRSS feed be used for raster image?

Tags: georss

GeoRSS can be used to show vector data (point, line, polygon, etc). Can it be used to show raster image, say GeoTIFF? Is it part of the specification?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not technically part of the specification, either of [GeoRSS simple](http://georss.org/simple) or [GeoRSS GML](http://georss.org/gml). However the specification does supply a specification for a bounding box, for example (in GeoRSS simple):

```xml
<georss:box>42.943 -71.032 43.039 -69.856</georss:box>
```

You could pass the bounding box and then pass the tiff image in the body of the message. Might require some massaging at the receiving end, but it should work. One example (for Atom feeds) might be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
  xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss">
  <title>Example title</title>
  <subtitle>Example subtitle</subtitle>
  <link rel="self" href="http://example.org/"/>
  <updated>2012-09-20T10:10:00Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name>om_henners</name>
  </author>
  <id>urn:uuid:c0d52100-02b7-11e2-8cc0-1078d2a24ff8</id>
  <entry>
    <id>http://universally.unique/URI</id>
    <title>Some image title</title>
    <updated>2012-09-20T10:10:00Z</updated>
    <content src="http://link.to/image.tif" type="image/tiff" />
    <summary>Some summary</summary>
    <georss:box>42.943 -71.032 43.039 -69.856</georss:box>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: Sorry om_henners. Your code didn't work. Is icon a valid tag for rss? Sorry, i am new to RSS.

Comment: Sorry about that - I've fixed the XML and [validated](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi) it (note the geoRSS element comes up as invalid, but it should work with an approriate reader). Also, the example is for an [Atom](http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/) feed rather than RSS itself, but almost all readers can understand both.